# Stop showing table footer in every page print css

Tags: html, css, datatable, datatables

I have a very long table in an HTML page. When I am printing the page the table footer `tfoot` is showing on each page at the bottom. **But I want it to show in the last page only**

In some tables, I didn't write any tbody because I used datatable to fill the data.

When I have added below code. The `tbody` is showing 1st then `tfoot` and the `tbody` content is showing.

Is there any CSS to show the `tfoot` at last but does not repeat in every page when printing??

```
table.table tfoot {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

The Table HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" id="customer_payment_view" class="customer_payment_view table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Agency Name</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Bill No</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th style="display: none;">Adjustment</th>
                <th>Pay Amount</th>
                <th>Pay Method</th>
                <th>Paid Through</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th style="display: none;"></th>
                <th class="7">Pay Amount</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use media queries to render the `tfoot` as if it were a `tbody`.

```
@media print {
    table.table tfoot {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
}
```

This way it only appears at the end of the table.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code

```
@media print {
    table.table tfoot {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hello World If this answer satisfying to you so please do Green tic mark. It's helpful for me and other.

Answer (score 1):

It can be hidden with media queries

```
 @media print {
    tfoot {
      display: none;
    }
 }
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/9afb3scw/4/

Comment: I can hide `tfoot` completely, but if I want it to show on the last page, who can I do it??